# ChromeVox voices list empty on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: chromium

In Chromium 76 on Ubuntu 18.04, I installed the ChromeVox extension version 53.0.2784.5. The menu for choosing voices is empty and it does not read any text. Sound generally works including the sound effects that ChromeVox generates. It is just the reading of the text that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to compile the Chrome OS version of Chrome: "If you‘re building Chrome from source and running it on desktop Linux, speech and braille won’t be included by default."

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/docs/accessibility/chromevox_on_desktop_linux.md